# How to transpose a data set into a particular way in R

Tags: r, dataset

Could you please help me with this one. I have a data set of this kind.

```
sample <- matrix(c(1, 'A', 0.17,
                   1, 'B', 0.80,
                   1, 'C', 0.10,
                   1, 'D', 0.35,
                   2, 'A', 0.44,
                   2, 'B', 0.24,
                   2, 'C', 0.39,
                   2, 'D', 0.65,
                   3, 'A', 0.61,
                   3, 'B', 0.94,
                   3, 'C', 0.19,
                   3, 'D', 0.65), nrow=12, ncol=3, byrow=T)

colnames(sample) <- c('year', 'country', 'X')
as.data.frame(sample)
```

which outputs

```
   year country    X
1     1       A 0.17
2     1       B  0.8
3     1       C  0.1
4     1       D 0.35
5     2       A 0.44
6     2       B 0.24
7     2       C 0.39
8     2       D 0.65
9     3       A 0.61
10    3       B 0.94
11    3       C 0.19
12    3       D 0.65
```

What trick do I need to get a data set like the following one?

```
year    A     B       C       D
1   0.17    0.80    0.10    0.35
2   0.44    0.24    0.39    0.65
3   0.61    0.94    0.19    0.65
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is missing the first line or two so I reformatted it a bit. Here's a solution using `tidyr`:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df <- read.table(text = 
      "1,  'A',    0.17
       1,  'B',    0.80
       1,  'C',    0.10
       1,  'D',    0.35
       2,  'A',    0.44
       2,  'B',    0.24
       2,  'C',    0.39
       2,  'D',    0.65
       3,  'A',    0.61
       3,  'B',    0.94
       3,  'C',    0.19
       3,  'D',    0.65", sep = ",", strip.white = TRUE)

colnames(df)<-c('year', 'country',  'X')

df %>%
  arrange(year, country) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = country, values_from = X)
#> # A tibble: 3 x 5
#>    year     A     B     C     D
#>   <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1     1  0.17  0.8   0.1   0.35
#> 2     2  0.44  0.24  0.39  0.65
#> 3     3  0.61  0.94  0.19  0.65
```

<sup>Created on 2020-04-10 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Glad you found it helpful, and welcome to Stack Overflow! Also, please consider accepting one of the given answers (click the check mark) if it solved your question.

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to accomplish is called reshaping a dataset from long to wide.

Using the reshape package, the following should do it:

d_long<- melt(yourdatasetname, id.vars = c("year"))

d_wide<-dcast(d_long, year ~ country, sum)

Answer (score 0):

Referring ColorStatistics's answer, The data set already looks in melt form. Just doing a dcast is enough.

```
> data<-as.data.frame(sample)
> library(data.table)
> dtable <- dcast(data = data, year~country) 
> dtable
      year    A    B    C    D
1    1 0.17  0.8  0.1 0.35
2    2 0.44 0.24 0.39 0.65
3    3 0.61 0.94 0.19 0.65
```

Answer (score 0):

An base R option is using `reshape` like below

```
dfout <- reshape(df,
                 direction = "wide",
                 idvar = "year",
                 timevar = "country")
```

such that

```
> dfout
  year  X.A  X.B  X.C  X.D
1    1 0.17  0.8  0.1 0.35
5    2 0.44 0.24 0.39 0.65
9    3 0.61 0.94 0.19 0.65
```